# No possibilities are ruled out

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, logic

Suppose that two binary (yes-no) qualities are being considered. Often (yes, actually!) I want to express that all four combinations are possible: yes-yes, yes-no, no-yes, no-no. Is there a concise way to convey this?

I *don't* want to say that the two are independent, because they often are not: merely that no possibilities can be ruled out.

Example: A person is from Party A or Party B, and votes for or against Party A's bill. (The person might be on either side, and could either defect or vote with her party.)

Non-example: A number is negative or not, and the number plus one is negative or not. (The combination "x is not negative, but x+1 is negative" cannot occur.)

Comment: You want a quick way to say that "no possibilities can be ruled out?" How about, "no possibilities can be ruled out?"

Comment: @EvanHarper: I don't want to say that because of the large risk that it's understood as "None of {(x negative), (x nonnegative), (x+1 negative), (x+1 nonnegative)} can be ruled out" rather than "None of {(x negative, x+1 negative), (x negative, x+1 nonnegative), (x nonnegative, x+1 negative), (x nonnegative, x+1 nonnegative)} can be ruled out". Of course this example is false...

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully grok the question. But, to answer the first bit:

> Suppose that two binary (yes-no) qualities are being considered. Often (yes, actually!) I want to express that all four combinations are possible: yes-yes, yes-no, no-yes, no-no. Is there a concise way to convey this?

Depending on how mathematically accurate you want to be, you could use one of:

> All *permutations* are possible.
>
> All *combinations* are possible.

Comment: I don't think permutations are applicable here, since order is not important.

Comment: @Jim Hence my note on mathematical accuracy. In my experience, even when inaccurate, _permutations_ appears to be preferred over _combinations_ when speaking about matters of choice. My guess is that this is because of the latter's more mainstream meaning of _to join_.

Answer (score 0):

You might say:

"*Given two binary values with non-zero probability for each combination*"

Or

"*Given two binary values whose Expected Value is a function of all combinations*"

Comment: The second would be true of my non-example as well. The first does not make the meaning of combinations clear (which is a real concern, since apparently it's difficult to describe the concept even in four paragraphs).